# How to register HttpHandler for all subfolders in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, httphandler, httpmodule

I would like to register an HttpHandler to include all subfolders of a root folder regardless of how far down they are nested.  I would have expected the behavior with the below code to do just that but in fact it only includes items directly in the root folder.

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="root/*" type="HandlerType, Assembly" />
</httpHandlers>
```

I can of course register as below to include anything that is second tier, however have yet to encounter a way to just say anything below root.

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="root/*/*" type="HandlerType, Assembly" />
</httpHandlers>
```

This is something hat has been bugging me for quite a while and I would love to hear of a simple solution.

I would like to clarify that when I say "root" I do not mean the root of the application and am not necessarily interested in sending all requests in the application to a module to be processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use HttpModule instead of HttpHandler.

Comment: This is of course always an option but I do not need the handler for all requests in the application just for all requests below a specific folder.  I might have been unclear in my question, by "root" I don't mean root of the site just of that branch in the folder tree.

Answer (score 22):

You don't need a separate web.config. Use the <location> element in your primary web.config:

```
<!-- Configuration for the "root" subdirectory. -->
<location path="root">
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="root" type="HandlerType, Assembly"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. Never knew about this element, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @ssougnez Thank you! I'm no expert, but I ran across this one once.

Answer (score 6):

You can create web.config in this "root" folder with path="*"

Comment: that is a great idea although in my case I am dealing with a url that does not match up to a folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a http **module** that checks the url for every incoming request. If the request url is in any folder you want your **handler** to handle, it does this:

- Put the full, original url in Context.Items
- Change the request path to some dummy value immediately below the handler's folder, matching the handler's configuration.

The **handler** will now be called, and it will find the dummy url in the request. 
It ignores this url, and processes the actual url that it will find in Context.Items.