# What are the rules around httpHandler paths in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, httphandler

Is there a good resource for the rules around how the httpHandler path property is used?

I am seeing mixed results for when my handler is called in different environments, so let me explain...

I want to allow for a URL such as:

```
http://mysite/_layouts/myCompany/rest/myservice.svc/param1/param2
```

I would like to invoke my handler only under "myCompany" folder/link so I put the following web.config file in the corresponding folder so as not to affect the rest of the application.  This works on some machines, but not on others:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add verb="*" path="myservice.svc" type="..." validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now, I've got to admit that I was a little surprised that this worked since it basically had to find the "myservice.svc" out of the "rest/myservice.svc/param1/param2" relative path, but it did find it - but only on two of my three test machines.  So, I tried the following on the machine that it failed on:

```
<add verb"*" path="rest/myservice.svc/*/*" type="..." validate="false"/>
```

This worked a few times and is now not working.  Being the logical type it really bothers me that after a bit if diligence I cannot explain this, but I haven't been able to get it to work again.  See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711094/how-to-register-httphandler-for-all-subfolders-in-asp-net) similar Stack Overflow question.

Note that the following does work, but it makes me resort to query string variables to provide parameters which is not ideal.

```
<add verb"*" path="rest/myservice.svc/*" type="..." validate="false"/>
```

I looked into the parent web.config files along the way on two machines that give different results to see how they define any httpHandlers and nothing popped out as a problem.

So, I'm looking for an understanding of how this path is utilized.

For what it's worth, this is running in a SharePoint site (hence the "sharepoint" tag on this question) and I am using this to provide REST (simple "text/xml") instead of SOAP.  I do not want to use full blown WCF because that rocks the boat a little too much many installations of SharePoint so I'm using an HTTP Handler instead.

In addition, the error I'm getting is the following:

```
virtualPath   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result) 
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) 
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, Boolean flowContext) 
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer is still welcome, but here I found a simple workaround.  So simple it bothers me that I didn't think of it before...

Since I own the folder/url from a certain point, I can just make sure that everything goes through my handler:

```
<add verb"*" path="*" type="..." validate="false"/>
```

How simple can it get :-S.

A side benefit of this is that I can better report an error for improper URLs.  I may decide to use a handler factory instead of a handler; then the only change is the **type** that is specified.

Comment: The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955417/httphandler-to-hook-the-svc-requests) may be relevant.