# How do you specify a single IIS handler mapping path that applies to all URIs under a single subdirectory?

Tags: iis, coldfusion, lucee

How can I configure a single IIS handler mapping path to allow all traffic starting with /rest/*, regardless of the number of subdirectories/subpaths, to be forwarded to ColdFusion?

Background:  We run Lucee 4.5 behind IIS 8 connected with BonCode on our production environment.  We are trying to implement our first of many REST endpoints using the native REST functionality in Lucee.  As a result, all of our REST URIs begin with /rest/ even though this is not configured anywhere as a physical or virtual directory.  I am able to add *individual* handler mappings to IIS in order to successfully pass traffic to *specific subdirectories* to ColdFusion.

The following are all examples of REST URIs and the associated handler mapping path that I had to add in order to get them to work.  I would like to add a single handler mapping to encompasses them all.

```
REST endpoint:  /rest/logout
IIS handler mapping path:  /rest/*

REST endpoint:  /rest/service/callback
IIS handler mapping path:  /rest/service/*
(the first mapping path of /rest/* would not work for "deeper" subdirectories).
```

Is there a way I can specify "all traffic beginning with /rest/* regardless of the number of subdirectories"?  It seems like there has to be a way to accomplish this without needing to add new entries for every new subdirectory that comes along ... ?  Many thanks.

Comment: I am using Lucee 4.5 with IIS7. Whenever I try & make a REST API request, I get a 404, "Page Not Found. On my laptop with ACF, everything works fine?  Do I have to add some kind of setting in the 'web.config', to make the REST API work on Lucee [Apache/Tomcat] on Windows 2008R2? I am tearing my hair out over this issue. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just to let you know, I have used this.webAdminPassword = 'mypasssord' and RestInitApplication(dirPath,serverMapping) etc part correctly, so I feel it is an IIS to Lucee issue?

Answer (score 2):

Found it.  Apparently my search-fu was weak last weak when I posted the original question.  I went looking again and found a solution!

[How to register HttpHandler for all subfolders in Asp.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711094/how-to-register-httphandler-for-all-subfolders-in-asp-net)

In a nutshell you define a  object in the web.config that maps to the subdirectory/URI (in my case, /rest), and then add a single wildcard handler to that location which handles all requests under that URI.

Comment: How about just uncommenting the following in 'web.xml': <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>CFMLServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: Looking at your answer, I have cobbled together this, but I haven't tested it yet in my web.config, for fear of blowing up my VPS: <location path="rest">
   <system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="/rest" type="BonCode-Tomcat-CFC-Handler"/>
  </httpHandlers>
   </system.web>
 </location>